# Nodemailer gmail copy

Tags: node.js, smtp, gmail, nodemailer

I am using nodemailer to send email using gmail, the email as send, but it store in   on gmail account.
Any parameter on nodemailer to disable storage copy on send email?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using a gmail smtp service this situation is not preventable. You have only 2 workarounds, first is to use another service (obviously) or use a filter from gmail side to delete mail from a specific field. The below reference is quite old but still valid.

Reference : 
https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/gmail/reIlN3wHNYw/cznTPjdAa4IJ

On how to create a filter : 
https://support.google.com/mail/answer/6579?hl=en